# How to describe a scenario that is close to the real conditions

Tags: phrase-requests, academia

I am writing a technical paper that includes economic analysis. In one section, I need to give a justification for choosing interest rates used in the study. I am trying to say the interest rates were chosen according to the reports of the central bank of the country to make the results of the study **reliable and closer to the real conditions**.

I am looking for an elegant and academically acceptable phrase or word to describe this.

Comment: 'Realistic' means 'representing things in a way that is accurate and true to life' [OALD, I believe]

Comment: It sounds like you could have chosen any interest rate to illustrate your analysis, but chose a specific rate from a specific central bank. You could preface your paragraph with an expression like this: “To illustrate the concept, we  have taken rate data from X”. BTW, the Central Bank of Ireland is a good source. They seem to have more lively writers than other central banks, based on what I’ve seen on the BIS website.

Comment: If your analysis is theoretical/general in nature, you might consider something like "Interest rates were selected from the country's central bank reports so as to have a verifiable test case."

Comment: *The interest rates used reflect those of the central bank, a reliable indicator of conditions...*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reliable is a good word, don't change it.

For the other part I was thinking of ***accurate*** which means:

> agreeing with facts ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/accurate))

*Accurate* describes well noun like *[results](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=accurate%20%2A&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t2%3B%2Caccurate%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Baccurate%20and%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Baccurate%20information%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Baccurate%20knowledge%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Baccurate%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Baccurate%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Baccurate%20as%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Baccurate%20account%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Baccurate%20than%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Baccurate%20description%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Baccurate%20results%3B%2Cc0), [measurements, information](https://www.google.com/search?q=accurate%20meaning&sxsrf=ALeKk01pixZOIa870REOGuYCF4RJyAXcKQ%3A1628968178432&source=hp&ei=8hQYYcnqF4_0gQbH5Li4Bg&iflsig=AINFCbYAAAAAYRgjArdb745wIOor7xD7p7crFUac0W-g&oq=Accurate%20&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAEYADIJCCMQJxBGEPkBMgQIABBDMgQIABBDMgUIABCRAjIECAAQQzIECAAQQzIFCAAQkQIyBQgAEJECMgcIABCxAxBDMggIABCABBCxAzoECCMQJzoQCC4QsQMQgwEQxwEQ0QMQQzoLCC4QgAQQsQMQgwE6EQguEIAEELEDEIMBEMcBEKMCOhEILhCABBCxAxCDARDHARDRAzoFCAAQgAQ6CggAELEDEMkDEEM6BQgAEJIDUJsHWKMVYPw0aABwAHgAgAHsAYgBhAiSAQU1LjMuMZgBAKABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz)*.

*[Factual](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/factual#factual__1)* is close in meaning, but it is not very commonly used to describe *results.*

But since it is not a single word that you are looking for, you could also use expressions like:

> ***agree with facts***

or

> ***be consistent with reality***

I particularly recommend ***consistent*** which means:

> acting or done in the same way over time, especially so as to be fair or accurate ([OxfordL](https://www.google.com/search?q=consistent%20with%20meaning&sxsrf=ALeKk00oMEH-lIMMMARkxFWAKyJSVJR_lQ%3A1628969275571&source=hp&ei=OxkYYeT0IJCD8gKY05L4Dw&iflsig=AINFCbYAAAAAYRgnS5XuUtptTvAwD6yJz5g3ppJbyFGh&oq=consistent%20w&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAEYATIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQ6BAgjECc6BQgAEJECOggIABCABBCxAzoLCC4QgAQQsQMQgwE6EQguEIAEELEDEIMBEMcBEKMCOg0IABCABBCHAhCxAxAUOgQIABBDOhEILhCABBCxAxCDARDHARCvAToICAAQsQMQkQI6BwgAELEDEEM6DAgAELEDEEMQRhD5AToHCAAQgAQQCjoSCAAQgAQQhwIQsQMQFBBGEPkBUO4HWNwuYLVCaABwAHgAgAG8AogB2AuSAQcyLjkuMC4xmAEAoAEB&sclient=gws-wiz))

and

> in agreement with other facts or with typical or previous behaviour, or having the same principles as something else ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/consistent))

So your sentence could be written as:

> the interest rates were chosen according to the reports of the central bank of the country to make the results of the study ***reliable and consistent with reality/accurate***.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using the word **prevailing**, which [Collins dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/prevailing) defines in a number of mays including "predominant" and "prevalent," but which I see used in this type of writing to mean (more or less) "existing" or "real-world."

My complete suggestion:  Your method is attempting to **replicate prevailing conditions** in [whatever region your article addresses].

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps ***authentic*** serves your purpose.

> ... the interest rates were chosen according to the reports of the
> central bank of the country to make the results of the study <strike>reliable
> and closer to the real conditions</strike> ***authentic***.

Lexico:

> **[authentic](https://www.lexico.com/definition/authentic)**
> *ADJECTIVE*
> **1.2** Based on facts; accurate or reliable.
>
> ‘What lacked so far is an authentic compilation of facts about this
> treasure trove of nature.’

Comment: I think authentic mean original and not fake. I am not sure if this is what I am looking for.